# warnings in xcode 4.2 objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, warnings

i created an iPad application, in which i am fetching data from URL,
when i write this code it shows me this warning `initWithContentsOfURL is deprecated`

here is the code snippet,

```
NSString *mainstr;

NSURL *urlr=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc.com/default.aspx?id=G"];
NSURLRequest *reqr=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlr];
[webViewq loadRequest:reqr];

mainstr=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:urlr];
```

also in tableView it shows me this warning,`initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier: is deprecated`

here is the code snippet, in which i am creating one label inside each row

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell"; 

if(cell == nil){


            cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x = 0; 
            frame.origin.y = 0;
            frame.size.height = 40;
            frame.size.width = 180;


            UILabel *capitalLabelI = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
            capitalLabelI.tag = CapitalTag;
            capitalLabelI.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];

}
capitalLabelI.text=[@" " stringByAppendingString:[a objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
```

and when i call multiple parametrized method, it shows me this warning,

method name:

`-(void)recentquote:(NSString *)sym:(int)i`

call syntex:

`[self recentquote:l3:i];`

warning:

`Instance method '-recentquote::' not found (return type default to 'id')'`

**Help me guys !!**

***Thanks In Advance !!***

Comment: If your given URL is Live then please remove it and put demo url...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the call syntax should be

```
[self recentquote:l3 :i];
```

(note at the space in between), I suggest renaming your function anyway.

when it say it's deprecated, it simply means some time in the future, Apple might remove this method all together, it's not longer supported. So change your

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
```

to

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                            reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

[Check the documentation for available style and what it means](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

EDIT :

I suggest changing it, maybe to

```
- (void)recentQuote:(NSString *)quote withIndex:(int)index;
```

then to call it use

```
[self recentQuote:@"OK" withIndex:2];
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
initWithContentsOfURL
```

use:

```
initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:
```

or

```
initWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:
```

instead of

```
initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:
```

use:

```
initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:
```

And you should change the declaration of:

```
-(void)recentquote:(NSString *)sym:(int)i
```

to:

```
-(void)recentquote:(NSString *)sym someArg:(int)i
```

Seems like you are really new to objective-c and iPad development, I strongly recommand you to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development